# Adding values to ARGS in perl mason

Tags: perl, redirect, args, mason

I want to add values to my ARGS before I pass that as a parameter in the redirect call.

I tried

```
%ARGS{session-id} = 'value1';
```

Gives syntax error. Can you please suggest the right away. And are the keys with hyphen in the name are not allowed ? If not how can I pass that to my redirect call as the component I am redirecting to is expecting a 'session-id' from %ARGS.

Comment: Thanks for replying. That is giving syntax error.

Comment: You probably should give more context when asking questions in the future; the code snippet you've supplied is a Perl assignment statement, and it probably would help to clarify if you showed how you're trying to fit it into a Mason template.  Also, there's probably an easier way to do what you're doing, but I'd need to see the context --- and how you're going to use `%ARGS` once the assignment has run --- to be able to suggest it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
$ARGS{'session-id'} = 'value1';
```

`session-id` is not a valid identifier in Perl; hash keys can *only* be used unquoted if they are valid identifiers.

Also, use `$` as the sigil (the de-referencing character in front of the variable name) when accessing a single element of a hash; `@` when accessing multiple elements of a hash; and `%` only when accessing the entire hash (or in Perl 5.20 and up, when accessing both keys and values of part of a hash).